# using boto3 and Python how to create AWS MFA authorized session which can be used by other roles

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

**SCENARIO**

I have two AWS accounts linked to a third aws account, main account. 
The accounts names, for instance, are `aws_acc_main`, `aws_acc_1`, `aws_acc_2`

`aws_main` is used to maintain the users, groups and roles for the other two accounts. however, except IAM no other services are used in the main account.

Using `boto3` and `Python` I want to get `ec2` instances for the account-1 and account-2

Thr AWS configuration looks like:

**.aws/credentials file**

```
[aws_acc_main]
aws_access_key_id=AKJFJHNUCTYUUAPW
aws_secret_access_key = 2uldfr94tuowjuHUKbnBIby8jhfdgjh
```

**.aws/config**

```
[aws_acc_main]
output = json
region = eu-west-2

[profile aws_acc_1]
source_profile = aws_acc_main
output = json
region = eu-west-2
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ACC1_ROLE
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::111111111110:mfa/ABCD

[profile aws_acc_2]
source_profile = aws_acc_main
output = json
region = eu-west-2
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::111111111112:role/ACC2_ROLE
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::111111111110:mfa/ABCD
```

Now the python files.

**test1.py**

```
sessions = ['aws_acc_1', 'aws_acc_2']
for session_name in sessions:
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=session_name)

    ec2 = session.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-2')
    resources = ec2.describe_instances()
```

**test2.py**

```
mfa_code = raw_input("Enter the MFA code: ")
client = boto3.client('sts')
response = client.get_session_token(
    DurationSeconds=3600, 
    SerialNumber='arn:aws:iam::111111111110:mfa/ABCD', 
    TokenCode=mfa_code
)
credentials = response['Credentials']

for session_name in sessions:
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=session_name, 
        aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken'],
    )
    ec2Client = session.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-2')
    resources = ec2.describe_instances()
```

**PROBLEM**

The first (`test1.py`) works OK but I have to provide `MFA` for each account in every iteration.

The second file (`test2.py`) does not give any errors either but it does not read the `EC2` service of `aws_acc_1` and `aws_acc_2`, instead it only get the ec2 service of `aws_acc_main`, which has nothing in it. It does not even give any error.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

I want to give MFA only once for the entire session. Then, I want to switch roles without providing MFA again and again. It means I want to fix the **`test2.py`**.

**QUESTION**

In AWS web client, once I login using my userid, password and MFA, I can switch roles without proving MFA again and again. That is what I want to do.

If I use boto3 to create a session, how can I use the same session to switch roles to different accounts without providing MFA again and again?

*Please note... that an important thing in this scenario is that the `aws_acc_1` and `aws_acc_2` are part of `aws_acc_main` and the MFA is handled only through `aws_acc_main`.*

Comment: I cannot comment on other asks, but the reason you are getting details from aws_acc_main in test2.py because returned credentials are for that account. For other two accounts, you should call assume role and you can provide MFA token while calling hence get session token is not required.  
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role

Comment: @sudo Thanks! I was already switching roles throught he credentials and config files. client.assume_role(...) is just another way of switching the role. But the problem remains there that is, providing MFA code again and again.

Comment: I don't think support for this is available in boto yet (https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1179), but there is a snippet on that page by igoralveslima which shows how it can be done by modifying the session to use the file cache.